# Turning off / Hiding the Touch Bar - MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: objective-c, macos, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have extensively searched internet for how to programatically turn off the Touch Bar, but have had no luck so far in finding a solution.

I know this is possible due to Apple's "QuickTime" app turning off the Touch Bar when a video is playing after the on screen controls fade away.

Would there be an official way to do this, or even a "hacky" way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt there is a public API or supported way to do this. So just keep that in mind if you are planning to submit to the Mac App Store or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to turn off the touch bar using the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

function enableTouchBar() {

    local presentationModeProperties="<dict><key>app</key><string>fullControlStrip</string><key>appWithControlStrip</key><string>fullControlStrip</string><key>fullControlStrip</key><string>app</string></dict>"

    defaults delete com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeGlobal
    defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeFnModes $presentationModeProperties

    launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.controlstrip.plist
    launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touchbar.agent.plist
    launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.touchbar.user-device.plist
    pkill "ControlStrip"
    pkill "Touch Bar agent"
    pkill Dock
}

function disableTouchBar() {

    defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModeGlobal -string fullControlStrip

    launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.controlstrip.plist
    launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touchbar.agent.plist
    launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.touchbar.user-device.plist
    pkill "ControlStrip"
    pkill "Touch Bar agent"
    pkill Dock
}

{
    if [ "$1" == "enable" ]; then
        enableTouchBar
    elif [ "$1" == "disable" ]; then
        disableTouchBar
    else
        printf "\\nUsage:\\n\\tTouchBar enable\\n\\tTouchBar disable\\n\\n"
    fi
}
```

Please note, System Integrity Protection must be disabled `$ csrutil disable` in recovery mode

References:

https://github.com/HiKay/TouchBarDisabler
https://gist.github.com/JamesMarino/1c628e9ad57e21684cd5e8ec139b7e98